# Not able to run the flutter firebase web app on google chrome

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I am new to flutter firebase web app development.
I tried to run the the project using `flutter run -d chrome --release`
The end result is as shown in the screen shot below

[image]

How may I configure it correctly to display the elements of the UI.
Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something is throwing null, that's why grey screen is coming . Check if any value is assigned null.